# How can I redirect user to view after login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5 I would like to redirect the user to specific view after they log in. I think I need to change this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Let's suppose I want it to redirect to a view called myView, and it must use https. What should I write in the ActionLink to do this?

Comment: Your login POST method can just include `return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");`. [Refer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to **is return a different view in the action**

Hit the action as you are doing

```
Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Now in the Login Action just after all of your validations are true add this:

**`return View("Your different view path");`**